# Android widget access sharedpreferences

Tags: android, widget

I have some issue access my sharedprefereces from my widget. I am trying to check how many contacts I selected in my contact list picker. I am checking in the 'onEnable' method

```
public void onEnabled(Context context) 
{
    Log.i(TAG,"in onEnabled");

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("settings_category",0);
    Log.i(TAG,"Total Number of Contacts: " + sharedPrefs.getInt("numContacts", 0));
    if(sharedPrefs.getInt("numContacts", 0) == 0)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"NO CONTACTS");
        //OPEN settingsprefactivity.java
        Intent con_intent = new Intent(context, ContactPrefActivity.class);
        con_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(con_intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Contacts Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I run I get 0 contacts, even though in my preference activity says 1. I don't think I am accessing the right context or something?

**UPDATE: ADDED CODE**
Below is the code where I write to the shared preferences.

```
private void addContact(String contactName, String contactPhone)
{
    Log.i(TAG,"In Function: addContact");
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();

    if(isDuplicateContact(contactName,contactPhone)){
        Log.i(TAG,"Contact Already Exists");

        Toast.makeText(this,"Contact Already in List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
    else{
        Log.i(TAG,"Add new Contact");
        Log.i(TAG,"Name: " + contactName);
        Log.i(TAG,"Phone: " + contactPhone);
        prefEditor.putString("contact_"+contactName.replaceAll("\\s","") + contactPhone.replaceAll("[ ()-]",""),contactName + "|" + contactPhone);
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int numContacts = sharedPrefs.getInt("numContacts", 0);
        prefEditor.putInt("numContacts",numContacts+1);
        prefEditor.commit();
    }
    showPreference();
}
```

Comment: how do you write to shared preference?. Post your code

Comment: i posted code. it shows where i add the sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing the wrong thing

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```